# How to get Perforce (P4Api.net) Workspace Path

Tags: c#, perforce, p4api.net

```
var P4USER = p4Config.P4USER;
var P4PORT = p4Config.P4PORT;
var P4CLIENT = p4Config.P4CLIENT;
var P4PASSWD = p4Config.P4PASSWD;

Perforce.P4.Server srv = new Perforce.P4.Server(new ServerAddress(P4PORT));
Perforce.P4.Repository p4 = new Perforce.P4.Repository(srv);
p4.Connection.UserName = P4USER;
p4.Connection.SetClient(P4CLIENT);
p4.Connection.Connect(new Perforce.P4.Options());
p4.Connection.Login(P4PASSWD);
```

I using P4Api.net and login done. but how can I get my worksapce path ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found solution , so I answer by my self.

```
string P4CLIENT = "YourWorkSpaceName";    
Client c = p4.GetClient(P4CLIENT);
//here
Console.WriteLine(c.Root);
```